# Xcode : UNIX Command-Line Tools Installation

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line, macports

I'm trying to install MacPorts but it needs command-line support to be installed with Xcode (which is an option during installation)

is there any way I could install UNIX command line support with Xcode without re-installing Xcode?

Comment: You might as well just re-install Xcode (and upgrade to the most recent version 3.2.x while you're at it).

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling Xcode is non destructive so best to just do that. Your projects will all still be available.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of packages in Xcode

## apple sign-on to download

```
http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg
```

## to-do additional installer flag

```
 [-showChoicesXML] [-applyChoiceChangesXML <pathToFile>]
 [-showChoicesAfterApplyingChangesXML <pathtoFile>]
```

## install (use gui, cli still incomplete /Developer/Library, etc.)

```
hdid ~/Downloads/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg
sudo installer -verbose -target / /Volumes/Xcode\ and\ iOS\ SDK/Xcode\ and\ iOS\ SDK.mpkg
sudo umount -f /Volumes/Xcode\ and\ iOS\ SDK
```

## confirm

```
xcodebuild -version
```

## uninstall

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Comment: better yet ... see http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2031/install-an-mpkg-from-the-command-line-on-osx for CLI related commands